# Get Http properties from Blazor WebAssembly - Server Side

Tags: server, blazor, client, blazor-webassembly, host

I have an application written on Blazor Web Assembly. Blazor WebAssembly has three projects, the Client, the Server and the Shared.

I am looking a way to get the following variables automatically on startup as the project may run on different enviroments, such as localhost, azure website, docker container, etc by provisioning different end-points avoiding the use of enviroment variable on app-settings or somewhere else:

1. Host
2. Port

If we need to take those variables from front-end (Client/razor component) we can do it this way:

```
navigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri();
```

Is there any way to archive the same from the server side, from a cs file of Startup?

Comment: If correctly understand you want to somehow get config values such as Host:Port for WASM at startup? Right?

Comment: Actually I need the server side to know the url which is hosted, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by getting config from Server where WASM is hosted, so it's not needed to store any env vars or appsettings for Client, only for Server, so it's ok as server (host) is not running on client.
Steps:

1. Add endpoint to Server where WASM is hosted

```
/// WASM invokes this instead of using appsettings.json.
app.MapGet("host/get_api_url", () => Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("API_URL"));
```

OR you can hardcode it

```
app.MapGet("host/get_api_url", () => "https://stackoverflow.com");
```

2. Invoke endpoint from WASM on startup

```
using HttpClient hostClient = new HttpClient();
string apiUrl = await hostClient.GetStringAsync(Path.Combine(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress, "host/get_api_url"));
```

Comment: I think that your answer indicates how to retrieve url on Client from Server without having AppSettings or EnvVars. The question was targeting more on the server project only, but in any case my API_URL returns null. Any idea?

Comment: Looks like you can use GetDisplayUrl method, but it can be achieved only under HttpContext, when app handle any incoming request.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.extensions.urihelper.getdisplayurl?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Do you have an example? I really do not get this example with GetDisplayUrl even I read the Microsoft page.

Comment: net 6 Minimaal Api
        using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;
.......
        app.MapGet($"/GetDisplayUrl", GetDisplayUrl);
.......
        static string GetDisplayUrl(HttpContext http)
        {
            string displayUrl = http.Request.GetDisplayUrl();
            return displayUrl;
        }